# crear una condicion

Tags: java, bluej

Hola buenas tardes compañeros, ya he investigado pero no puedo implementarlo.¿como le puedo hacer para que continué el ciclo hasta que se caiga la moneda?
es decir, que mientras la moneda no se caiga el programa se siga ejecutando hasta que lo haga, en caso contrario que la moneda se caiga el programa termine

```
 if(random<=33) 
 {
     System.out.println ("se cayo la moneda");
 }
 else if(random>33) 
 {
     System.out.println ("no se cayo la moneda ");
 }
```

Comment: lo que llamas "caerse la moneda" es cuando generas un número que guardas en random, hasta que sea mayor a 33? no te sirve un `while(moneda<=33)`?

Comment: tal como lo mencionan, prueba utilizando un `while`.

Comment: y si estoy utilizando  double random =Math.random()*(98)+1;

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
#Está escrito en Python pero la idea es la misma en cualquier lenguaje
import random

v= random.randint(1,50) #En una variable guardas el random

while v > 33: #Minetras v sea mayor que 33
    v = random.randint(1,50) #Creas un nuevo random en la misma variable
    print('No se cayó la moneda') #Muestras por pantalla el mensaje

if v <= 33: 
    print('Se cayó la moneda')
```

Espero lo puedas implementar en tu leguaje, respóndeme si hay algo que no te quedó claro

Comment: Seria bueno que la respuesta sea en Java

Answer (score 0):

Puedes poner las condicionales dentro de un ciclo `for` o crear un ciclo `while` o `do while`.

---

## Con un ciclo `for`

Para mantenerte en el ciclo `for` hasta que ***la moneda haya caído*** debes de hacer lo siguiente.

- al inicio del ciclo le reasignas el valor a la variable `random`.
- validas si `random` es meno o igual a 33
- de ser menor a 33 imprimes **se cayo la moneda**
- de ser mayor:

  1. imprimes **no se cayo la moneda**
  2. le restas 1 a la variable de control

```java
for (int i = 0; i = 1; i++ ){
    random = Math.random()*(98)+1;
    if(random<=33) {
        System.out.println ("se cayo la moneda");
    }
    else (random>33) {
        System.out.println ("no se cayo la moneda ");
        i--;//restas uno a tu variable de control
    }
}

//Lo puedes hacer de esta otra forma
for (int i = 0; i = 1; i++ ){
    random = Math.random()*(98)+1;
    if(random>33) {
        System.out.println ("no se cayo la moneda ");
        i--;//restas uno a tu variable de control
    }
}
System.out.println ("se cayo la moneda");
```

#### Como aclaración del `else if`.

El uso del `else if` es para especificar una nueva condición en caso de que la primera haya dado `false`. Se puden agregar tantos `else if` sean necesarios y cuando alguna de estos `else if` nos de `true` dejará de validar el resto de `else if`. También al final se pone terminando un `else` que será lo que se va a ejecutar cuando todas las validaciones hayan dado `false`. A este ultimo `else` se le conoce como `caso de default`.

---

## Ciclo `while`

```java
while(random>33){
    System.out.println ("no se cayo la moneda ");
    random = Math.random()*(98)+1;
}
System.out.println ("se cayo la moneda");
```

---

## Ciclo `do while`

```java
do {
    System.out.println ("no se cayo la moneda ");
    random = Math.random()*(98)+1;
} while (random >33);
System.out.println ("se cayo la moneda");
```

Comment: Es totalmente innecesario el segundo else if

Comment: es como lo tiene el, pero se puede agregar afuera el print, ya es cuestión de gustos

Comment: Bueno, es que hay 1 error:
Dentro del for hay un else if sin if.
Y otro comentario es que sería bueno mencionar que en el primer if, se puede cambiar el else if por un else

Comment: y si estoy utilizando  double random =Math.random()*(98)+1;?

Comment: @EduardoJiménez Gracias por la observación del esle if, no lo había notado, también voy a agregar lo que comentas

Comment: @OlderJimenez ya modifiqué los ejemplos usando la clase math, que es lo que estás usando